# How do you use custom fonts with React-native android?

Tags: android, fonts, webfonts, react-native

I'm having difficulty getting custom webfonts to work with react-native on android.

I have followed the instructions from here https://medium.com/@gattermeier/custom-fonts-in-react-native-for-android-b8a331a7d2a7#.w6aok6lpw but to no success.

I've tried with a few different fonts, still no joy.

**nb** I've tried renaming the font files, replaces dashes with underscores, all lowercase, and so on, but still no success.

Any help, greatly appreciated.  This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class MyBeltingApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
         Straigtline
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    fontFamily: 'GT-Walsheim-Bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyBeltingApp', () => MyBeltingApp);
```

Comment: can you please provide an answer to how you got this working?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @magicspon - where you manage to solve it? Facing the same problem - iOS works great, Android nothing... Tried everything...

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get the fonts working.

Created a fonts folder in the root of my project.

then in package.json

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": ["fonts"]
  }
```

then run `rnpm link assets`

huzzah...

nb. I didn't have to change any files names or anything.  they work with dashes just fine.