# react native custom fonts

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fonts

This question has been already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825276/how-to-add-custom-font-in-react-native-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875741/how-do-you-use-custom-fonts-with-react-native-android), but the answer is not satisfactory there. The fonts are not working on android but on iOS do. Maybe I made some mistake during the linking.

**How did I added fonts:**

1. Created folder `assets/fonts/` inside root folder.
2. Added

   ```
   "rnpm": { "assets": ["./assets/fonts"] }
   ```
3. `react-native link`
4. Console output was it successfully added assets to iOS and Android
5. Added fontFamily: 'MyCustomFontFamily' into styles.
6. Run on iOS, everything worked fine.
7. Run on Android, no typeface.
8. Checked the android project directory and the assets folder was present
9. I tried adding `(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'MyCustomFontFamily' : 'fonts/my_custom_font_family'` to go with the file name but this did not work wither.
10. Tried same variation as 9 without path or with extension but no luck
11. Read [here](https://gist.github.com/hilkeheremans/acb9949a06ced38ba15a2628f849e33a) to use weight, tried it, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, which had to do with the fact that, as you already know, **Android will read from the filename whilst iOS will read from the full name property**. And, indeed, I had mixed up my fonts' references.

The first thing I did to solve this was to double-check that my fonts were properly located in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/`.

Then I ended up renaming my fonts to the exact same name as the one used by iOS and using that name as a reference. Here is what I mean:

```
export const sansSerifLight = 'Aileron-Light'; // Filename is 'Aileron-Light.otf'
export const sansSerifRegular = 'Aileron-Regular'; // Filename is 'Aileron-Regular.otf'
export const sansSerifBold = 'Aileron-Bold'; // Filename is 'Aileron-Bold.otf'
export const serifRegular = 'LibreBaskerville-Regular'; // Filename is 'LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf'
export const serifBold = 'LibreBaskerville-Bold'; // Filename is 'LibreBaskerville-Bold.ttf'
export const serifItalic = 'LibreBaskerville-Italic'; // Filename is 'LibreBaskerville-Italic.ttf'
export const sansSerifTitle = 'ADAM.CG PRO'; // Filename is 'ADAM.CG PRO.otf'
export const serifTitle = 'Oranienbaum'; // Filename is 'Oranienbaum.ttf
```

And then :

```
<MyComponent style={{ fontFamily: serifTitle }} />
```

This really made things way less error-prone and easier to maintain for me.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for late reply. I took some time to get back to this. I have created a file where I put the correct String for the fonts based on the Platform. It is working now. Thank you for inspiration :)